# facing error while parsing date column with different formats

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime, strptime

my dataframe includes date in dd/mm/yy  & dd/mm/yyyy format but while converting them into pandas datetime it gives below error :

> ValueError: time data "02/11/21" doesn't match format "%m/%d/%Y", at position 129. You might want to try:
> - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
> - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
> - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

with this code `df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')`  it converts most of the values into NaT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%y` for YY format of year:

```
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format='%m/%d/%y', errors='coerce')
```

If there are both format of years `YY` and `YYYY` use:

```
df['date_column'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format='%m/%d/%y', errors='coerce') 
                       .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], 
                                              format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce'))
```